# I can't run graphical programs with sudo (Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: fonts, sudo, gui, gksu

If I try to run a program with GUI (e.g. Nautilus) as root, I'm just getting the following output:

```
gksu nautilus
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 9: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated.
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyCould not parse arguments: Anzeige kann nicht geöffnet werden:
```

Comment: Did you modified your ~/.fonts.conf ?

Comment: it's a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/backintime/+bug/1068437 or at least a warning that is worded strangly: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontconfig/+bug/1068549

Comment: I didn't modify it, but I just restored my home-directory from 12.04.

The font bug is solved now for me but still, I get the second error displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the bug report:

> This is just a warning to get people to migrate to XDG configuration layout, it is no bug in backintime.
>
> To get rid of the warning move `~/.fonts.conf` to `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` or if `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fontconfig` is set to that directory.

Comment: Thanks the first warning was solved by this.
But I still get: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyCould not parse arguments: Anzeige kann nicht geöffnet werden: